# Cmbiar og:image con Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5, facebook

Tengo una pagina en la que por razones ajenas a mí no tengo acceso al HEAD (cuestiones de empresa).

La cosa es que tengo actualmente la carga del `og:image` hecho mediante una llamada JQuery:

```
$('head').append('<meta property="og:image" content="<%=urlImagen%>">');
```

Veo en el código fuente generado que si que me aparece pero al pasarlo por el debugueador de Facebook me da el siguiente error:

> ```
> The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred 
>  from other tags.
> ```

La cosa es que no se si es posible (segun W3S no es recomendable pero ya me da un poco igual) poner el meta directamente en el cuerpo.

La cosa es que hasta llegar a entorno de producción no podría probarlo y me da miedo pasarlo y hacerlo fallar así que me gustaría saber si alguno puede darme una respuesta.

Ejemplo similar:

```
<html>
<head>
    ... 
    include de jQuery
    ...
</head>
<body>
    ...
     $('head').append('<meta property="og:image" content="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/9/99/MarioSMBW.png">');
    ...
</body
</html>
```

La cosa seria saber si así añadiendo el meta de esta manera facebook o twitter lo reconocerían. En el view generated source veo que me incluye bien el meta dentro del head, pero parece que no facebook no es capaz de leerlo. La cosa es saber si puedo llevar ese  dentro del body o no ya que los meta DEBEN ir en el head pero no se si poniéndolos en el body me las detectarían.

Comment: ¿Por qué has incluído la etiqueta jsp? Intenta crear un [mcve] e incluir el código y pasos para reproducir el error.

Comment: Porque realmente la imagen a meter en el content la calculo mediante codigo Java n JSP. La cosa es que luego he intenado simplicarlo.

Comment: Ya te he añadido un ejempo simplificandolo al absurdo para que veas cual es la idea y expuesto la pregunta de nuevo de otra manera.

Comment: Me parece que la pregunta está mejor, por otro lado, no sé si te funcionará en facebook o twitter. Lo que yo haría es hacer la prueba.

Comment: Eso había pensado pero para eso tengo que llegar a publicarlo y lo tenemos bastante restringido como para andar haciendo pruebas. He buscado algun dominio pulico en el que tirar una pagina para poder depurarla desde el debugger de Facebook pero no encuentro ninguna, xD

Comment: Hay muchas alternativas, por ejemplo, está GitHub pages. El "pero" es que está en inglés. En el [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) podríamos pedir orientación acercad de traducciones u otras alternativas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Respuesta parcial

Para probar si lo que quieres hacer funciona correctamente en un dominio independiente de la empresa puedes usar [GitHub pages](https://pages.github.com/) de forma muy sencilla usando el gestor de temas [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/).

## Instrucciones

### Crea un sitio en GitHub pages

1. Crea una cuenta en [GitHub](http://github.com)
2. Crea un nuevo repositorio usando `nombredeusario.github.io` como nombre del mismo
3. Haz clic en "Settings"
4. En la sección de GitHub pages haz clic en "Choose a theme"
5. Revisa los temas y escoge uno.
6. Te dará la opción de editar el archivo README. Si lo deseas, cancela para editarlo posteriormente.

### Crea una nueva página para probar tu código html

1. Ve al repositorio en GitHub
2. Agrega una página
3. Agrega el nombre de archivo con extensión .html
4. Agrega tu código
5. Guarda el código
6. Ve al enlace de la página, revisa el resultado

### Probar en la herramienta para desarrolladores

1. Ve la página de validación de Facebook o cualquier otro que quieras utilizar
2. Envía el URL de tu página y revisa los resultados.
3. Actualiza o publica una nueva pregunta, ahora sí lo más completa que puedas :)

### Ejemplo parcial

No se incluye la parte de prueba en Facebook

#### Repositorio

https://github.com/rubenrivera/rubenrivera.github.io/

#### Código Hola mundo

```
<html>
  <body>
    ¡Hola mundo!
  </body>
</html>
```

#### Enlace al archivo en GitHub

https://github.com/rubenrivera/rubenrivera.github.io/blob/master/holamundo.html

#### Enlace a la página publicada

Un enlace como este sería el que utilizarías para evaluar tu página en la herramienta para desarrolladores de Facebook o cualquier otro similar

https://rubenrivera.github.io/holamundo.html

## Referencias

[Creating a GitHub Pages site with the Jekyll Theme Chooser](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-github-pages-site-with-the-jekyll-theme-chooser/)

## Antecedentes

Conversación a través de comentarios a la pregunta.

---

> [Rubén:](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52644/cmbiar-ogimage-con-javascript/52811#comment93438_52644) Me parece que la pregunta está mejor, por otro lado, no sé si te funcionará en facebook o twitter. Lo que yo haría es hacer la prueba.

---

> [Endika Hernando:](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52644/cmbiar-ogimage-con-javascript/52811#comment93442_52644) Eso había pensado pero para eso tengo que llegar a publicarlo y lo tenemos bastante restringido como para andar haciendo pruebas. He buscado algun dominio pulico en el que tirar una pagina para poder depurarla desde el debugger de Facebook pero no encuentro ninguna, xD

---

> [Rubén:](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52644/cmbiar-ogimage-con-javascript/52811#comment93458_52644) Hay muchas alternativas, por ejemplo, está GitHub pages. El "pero" es que está en inglés. En el chat podríamos pedir orientación acercad de traducciones u otras alternativas.

---

Comment: Muchas gracias Ruben. Me pongo con ello, un saludo.

Comment: He podido hacer las pruebas y pasarlas para demostrar que tengo que cmbiar el HEAD asi que ya me han dejado meterle mano... gracias. Sabes si se puede dar por soucionada la pregunta?

Comment: Lo mejor sería que publicaras una respuesta indicando lo mencionado en tu comentario, con un poco más de detalle. Referencia: http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer